# CRC-16 and CRC-32 Checks

Tags: c#, crc32, crc16

I need help trying to verify CRC-16 values (also need help with CRC-32 values). I tried to sit down and understand how CRC works but I am drawing a blank.

My first problem is when trying to use an online calculator for calculating the message "`BD001325E032091B94C412AC`" into **CRC16 = 12AC**. The documentation states that the last two octets are the CRC16 value, so I am inputting "`BD001325E032091B94C4`" into the site http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html and receive 5A90 as the result instead of 12AC.

**Does anybody know why these values are different and where I can find code for how to calculate CRC16 and CRC32 values (I plan to later learn how to do this but times doesn't allow right now)?**

Some more messages are as following:

```
16000040FFFFFFFF00015FCB  
3C00003144010405E57022C7  
BA00001144010101B970F0ED  
3900010101390401B3049FF1  
09900C800000000000008CF3  
8590000000000000000035F7  
00900259025902590259EBC9  
0200002B00080191014BF5A2  
BB0000BEE0014401B970E51E  
3D000322D0320A2510A263A0  
2C0001440000D60000D65E54
```

--Edit--

I have included more information. The documentation I was referencing is TIA-102.BAAA-A (from the TIA standard). The following is what the documentation states (trying to avoid copyright infringement as much as possible):

> The Last Block in a packet comprises several octets of user information and / or
>   pad octets, followed by a 4-octet CRC parity check. This is referred to as the
>   packet CRC.
>
> The packet CRC is a 4-octet cyclic redundancy check coded over all of the data
>   octets included in the Intermediate Blocks and the octets of user information of
>   the Last Block. The specific calculation is as follows.
>
> Let k be the total number of user information and pad bits over which the packet
>   CRC is to be calculated. Consider the k message bits as the coefficients of a
>   polynomial M(x) of degree k–1, associating the MSB of the zero-th message
>   octet with x^k–1 and the LSB of the last message octet with x^0. Define the
>   generator polynomial, GM(x), and the inversion polynomial, IM(x).
>
> GM(x) = x^32 + x^26 + x^23 + x^22 + x^16 + x^12 + x^11 + x^10 + x^8 + x^7 + x^5 +
>   x^4 + x^2 + x + 1
>
> IM(x) = x^31 + x^30 + x^29 + ... + x^2 + x +1
>
> The packet CRC polynomial, FM(x), is then computed from the following formula.
>
> FM(x) = ( x^32 M(x) mod GM(x) ) + IM(x)              modulo 2, i.e., in GF(2)
>
> The coefficients of FM(x) are placed in the CRC field with the MSB of the zero-th
>   octet of the CRC corresponding to x^31 and the LSB of the third octet of the CRC
>   corresponding to x^0.

In the above quote, I have put `^` to show powers as the formatting didn't stay the same when quoted. I'm not sure what goes to what but does this help?

Comment: Where did you get the 12AC value from?

Comment: The last two bytes of BD001325E032091B94C412AC. If you look at the block of examples, it appears that the last two bytes are always a checksum.

Comment: There could be different CRC-16 values, that entirely depends on the polynomial used.

Comment: Gabriel: "The documentation" = **what** documentation?

Comment: You are right in my not identifying which documentation. I have edited my question to show more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Read [Ross Williams tutorial on CRCs](https://www.zlib.net/crc_v3.txt) to get a better understanding of CRC's, what defines a particular CRC, and their implementations.
2. The [reveng website](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/) has an excellent catalog of known CRCs, and for each the CRC of a test string (nine bytes: "123456789" in ASCII/UTF-8).  Note that there are *22 different 16-bit CRCs* defined there.

The reveng software on that same site can be used to reverse engineer the polynomial, initialization, post-processing, and bit reversal given several examples as you have for the 16-bit CRC.  (Hence the name "reveng".)  I ran your data through and got:

```
./reveng -w 16 -s 16000040FFFFFFFF00015FCB 3C00003144010405E57022C7 BA00001144010101B970F0ED 3900010101390401B3049FF1 09900C800000000000008CF3 8590000000000000000035F7 00900259025902590259EBC9 0200002B00080191014BF5A2 BB0000BEE0014401B970E51E 3D000322D0320A2510A263A0 2C0001440000D60000D65E54

width=16  poly=0x1021  init=0xc921  refin=false  refout=false  xorout=0x0000  check=0x2fcf  name=(none)
```

As indicated by the "(none)", that 16-bit CRC is not any of the 22 listed on reveng, though it is similar to several of them, differing only in the initialization.

The additional information you provided is for a 32-bit CRC, either CRC-32 or CRC-32/BZIP in the reveng catalog, depending on whether the bits are reversed or not.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer for now as I don't have a lot of time to dedicate to learning about CRCs and it sounds like I have a lot to work towards for the ones I'm receiving. Thank you for the links and info. I'll revisit these some day and try to make sense of them.

Comment: @ygoe Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I have a class I converted from a C++ I found in internet, it uses a long to calculate a CRC32. It adhere to the standard and is the one use by PKZIP, WinZip and Ethernet. To test it, use Winzip and compress a file then calculate the same file with this class, it should return the same CRC. It does for me.

```
public class CRC32
{
    private int[] iTable;

    public CRC32() {
       this.iTable = new int[256];
       Init();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the iTable aplying the polynomial used by PKZIP, WINZIP and Ethernet.
     */
    private void Init()
    {
       // 0x04C11DB7 is the official polynomial used by PKZip, WinZip and Ethernet.
       int iPolynomial = 0x04C11DB7;

       // 256 values representing ASCII character codes.
       for (int iAscii = 0; iAscii <= 0xFF; iAscii++)
       {
          this.iTable[iAscii] = this.Reflect(iAscii, (byte) 8) << 24;

          for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
          {
             if ((this.iTable[iAscii] & 0x80000000L) == 0) this.iTable[iAscii] = (this.iTable[iAscii] << 1) ^ 0;
             else this.iTable[iAscii] = (this.iTable[iAscii] << 1) ^ iPolynomial;
          }
          this.iTable[iAscii] = this.Reflect(this.iTable[iAscii], (byte) 32);
       }
    }

    /**
     * Reflection is a requirement for the official CRC-32 standard. Note that you can create CRC without it,
     * but it won't conform to the standard.
     *
     * @param iReflect
     *           value to apply the reflection
     * @param iValue
     * @return the calculated value
     */
    private int Reflect(int iReflect, int iValue)
    {
       int iReturned = 0;
       // Swap bit 0 for bit 7, bit 1 For bit 6, etc....
       for (int i = 1; i < (iValue + 1); i++)
       {
          if ((iReflect & 1) != 0)
          {
             iReturned |= (1 << (iValue - i));
          }
          iReflect >>= 1;
       }
       return iReturned;
    }

    /**
     * PartialCRC caculates the CRC32 by looping through each byte in sData
     *
     * @param lCRC
     *           the variable to hold the CRC. It must have been initialize.
     *           <p>
     *           See fullCRC for an example
     *           </p>
     * @param sData
     *           array of byte to calculate the CRC
     * @param iDataLength
     *           the length of the data
     * @return the new caculated CRC
     */
    public long CalculateCRC(long lCRC, byte[] sData, int iDataLength)
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < iDataLength; i++)
       {
          lCRC = (lCRC >> 8) ^ (long) (this.iTable[(int) (lCRC & 0xFF) ^ (int) (sData[i] & 0xff)] & 0xffffffffL);
       }
       return lCRC;
    }

    /**
     * Caculates the CRC32 for the given Data
     *
     * @param sData
     *           the data to calculate the CRC
     * @param iDataLength
     *           then length of the data
     * @return the calculated CRC32
     */
    public long FullCRC(byte[] sData, int iDataLength)
    {
       long lCRC = 0xffffffffL;
       lCRC = this.CalculateCRC(lCRC, sData, iDataLength);
       return (lCRC /*& 0xffffffffL)*/^ 0xffffffffL);
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the CRC32 of a file
     *
     * @param sFileName
     *           The complete file path
     * @param context
     *           The context to open the files.
     * @return the calculated CRC32 or -1 if an error occurs (file not found).
     */
    long FileCRC(String sFileName, Context context)
    {
          long iOutCRC = 0xffffffffL; // Initilaize the CRC.

          int iBytesRead = 0;
          int buffSize = 32 * 1024;
          FileInputStream isFile = null;
          try
          {
             byte[] data = new byte[buffSize]; // buffer de 32Kb
             isFile = context.openFileInput(sFileName);
             try
             {
                while ((iBytesRead = isFile.read(data, 0, buffSize)) > 0)
                {
                   iOutCRC = this.CalculateCRC(iOutCRC, data, iBytesRead);
                }
                return (iOutCRC ^ 0xffffffffL); // Finalize the CRC.
             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                // Error reading file
             }
             finally
             {
                isFile.close();
             }
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
             // file not found
          }
          return -1l;
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few parameters to CRC calculations: Polynomial, initial value, final XOR... see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Specification_of_CRC) for details. Your CRC does not seem to fit the ones on the site you used, but you can try to find the right parameters from your documentation and use a different calculator, e.g. [this one](http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html) (though I'm afraid it doesn't support HEX input).

One thing to keep in mind is that CRC-16 is usually calculated over the data that is supposed to be checksummed *plus two zero-bytes*, e.g. you are probably looking for a `CRC16` function where `CRC16(BD001325E032091B94C40000) == 12AC`. With checksums calculated in this way, the CRC of the data with checksum appended will work out to 0, which makes checking easier, e.g. `CRC16(BD001325E032091B94C412AC) == 0000`

Comment: I have updated my original question to include more information.